# sql access how to return between dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

How do I specify a date range in MS Access? Is the below query correct? Do I have to put `"2/1/2010"` in quotes? Or do I have to do something like `date(2/1/2010)`?

```
SELECT [Occurrence Number] as Fld
  FROM [Lab Occurrence Form]
 WHERE [Practice Code]="ACCIM"
   AND [1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]="1.1 Specimen Mislabeled"
   AND ([Occurrence Date] Between 2/1/2010 and 2/28/2010);
```

the following gives me a type mismatch

```
SELECT [Occurrence Number] as Fld FROM [Lab Occurrence Form] WHERE [1 0 Preanalytical (Before Testing)]="1.1 Specimen Mislabeled" AND [Occurrence Date] between "1/1/2009" and "2/2/2010";
```

Comment: how do u make the formatting so nice?

Comment: @user29823498750932874509823745 it's a matter of putting in hard returns. Be sure to put in hard returns when adding code to your questions to break things up. Then check the preview below your question to be sure the formatting is to your liking before posting. You can edit this question to see what I mean.

Comment: Just for future reference. Use the graphical query builder in Access and then look at the SQL. It would have placed the correct characters for you when using a date field.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ms-access uses the Jet engine which uses # for date literal:

```
SELECT Orders.*
  FROM Orders
 WHERE Orders.OrderDate Between #3/1/96# And #6/30/96#;
```

Comment: You can learn more about the Jet engine at:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966377.aspx

Comment: It is usually much better to use year, month, day. Month, day, year will usually suit Access, but it can get very confusing in locales other than the US.

Comment: I meant to learn about the SQL flavor used by the Jet engine.

Comment: If you don't like Jet/ACE, then why are you using it? If you're not willing to learn how it works, why are you using it?

Answer (score 2):

```
AND ([Occurrence Date] Between #2/1/2010# and #2/28/2010#
```

This is how you tell Access, to interpret something as date time.

Comment: It is usually much better to use year, month, day. Month, day, year will usually suit Access, but it can get very confusing in locales other than the US.

Comment: The key is that you need an unambiguous format, as Jet/ACE will interpret 3/4/2010 as a US data, no matter your local date settings. You might think yo're asking for 3 April, 2010, but Jet/ACE will think you're asking for March 4th, 2010. So, use DateSerial() or a date format that is unambigous (#1-Feb-2010#, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Ms access database uses the "#" for  presenting dates. So if you want to write 13/12/2013 as ms access acceptable form then you have to write it as #13/12/2013#.

**An example sql query for table called "test" with two fields id, and date.**

select * from test where date=#13/12/2013#.

**An example of a sql query for vb.net 2008 to find the database records between two dates**

"select * from info_session where i_date between # " & startingdate & " # and  # " & enddate & " #"

Answer (score 0):

The dates to use in select (in Microsoft) are defined as: "#"+month+"/"+day+"/" +year+"#"

the field day is a number 01,02---,31
the field month is a number 01,02 ...12
the field year is 2014, 2015 ...etc

you can build the SQL field dinamically

es. in vbscript

```
dt1="#"&month(date1)&"/"&day(Date1)&"/"&year(Date1)&"#"
dt2="#"&month(date2)&"/"&day(Date2)&"/"&year(Date2)&"#"
```

and then you can use the select in a field SQL

where the table Orders has a field named OrderDate
es.

```
SQL="select * from Orders where OrderDate Between " & dt1 & " and " dt2
```

now you can access the Database