# Convert String to Date in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, casting

I am trying to retrieve data from my `access` table based on `Date` column. My requirement is to display everything greater than the certain value. I am trying to `cast` my value, which is a `string` using Format `&CDate` function with `datetime` data type and it throws out as Overflow.

Here's query :

```
Select * from Events
Where Events.[Date] > cDate(Format("20130423014854","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

Sample Date Record Value from Table :  `2013-04-23 13:48:54.0`

`Events.[Date]` is a Date/Time type field in `access`

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17361338/edit) your question to clarify: Is the `Events.[Date]` field a `Date/Time` field or a `Text` field?

Comment: Done!! .. it's a Date/Time field

Comment: Okay, good. Have you tried just using `Where Events.[Date] > #2013-04-23 01:48:54#`?

Comment: the comparison value here is a string .. also when I used above, strangely it returned result set of >= .. I had 9 record with above values all them were displayed .. actual outcome should have been zero

Comment: RE: "Sample Date Record Value from Table : 2013-04-23 13:48:54.0" - Access `Date/Time` fields do not store values with fractional seconds. Is your [Events] table a native Access table?

Answer (score 22):

Use the `DateValue()` function to convert a `string` to `date` data type. That's the easiest way of doing this.

```
DateValue(String Date)
```

Comment: It would be nice to share an example

Comment: Example: DateValue ("6/30/2004") from this page: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datevalue.php

Answer (score 6):

In Access, click `Create > Module` and paste in the following code

```
Public Function ConvertMyStringToDateTime(strIn As String) As Date
ConvertMyStringToDateTime = CDate( _
        Mid(strIn, 1, 4) & "-" & Mid(strIn, 5, 2) & "-" & Mid(strIn, 7, 2) & " " & _
        Mid(strIn, 9, 2) & ":" & Mid(strIn, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(strIn, 13, 2))
End Function
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and save the module as `modDateConversion`.

Now try using a query like

```
Select * from Events
Where Events.[Date] > ConvertMyStringToDateTime("20130423014854")
```

--- Edit ---

Alternative solution avoiding user-defined VBA function:

```
SELECT * FROM Events
WHERE Format(Events.[Date],'yyyyMMddHhNnSs') > '20130423014854'
```

Comment: works with similar behavior as I mentioned earlier shows all records even with timestamp less than above value but of same date .. also I am looking for more direct way of implementation because this would be built in Java code .. so can't work with this function because I might now have access installed at target server

Comment: +1 Love the simplicity of the update to convert the date field for the comparison.

Comment: @MattDonnan Thanks. Unfortunately the downside is that if there is an index on the [Date] column it won't be used, but "you don't get something for nothing...".

Answer (score 2):

Basically, this will not work out

```
Format("20130423014854","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

the `format` function will only work if your string has correct format

```
Format (#17/04/2004#, "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

And you need to specify, what datatype of field `[Date]` is, because I can't put this value  `2013-04-23 13:48:54.0` under a General Date field (I use `MS access2007`).
You might want to view this topic: 
[select date in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168529/sql-access-how-to-return-between-dates)

Comment: Date is date/time type field configured in database

Answer (score 2):

```
cdate(Format([Datum im Format DDMMYYYY],'##/##/####') )
```

converts string without punctuation characters into date

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display all the records after 2014-09-01, add this to your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Events
WHERE Format(Events.DATE_TIME,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')  >= Format("2014-09-01 00:00:00","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```