# String to date in MS Access SQL statement gives type mismatch error

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2013, sqldatetime

Currently doing a data migration from a Microsoft Access database to a Microsoft SQL Server database using C#. I am trying to create a query to pull data from the Access database and order by two columns: `Surname` and `Date`. The challenge is that `Date` is a string in the following sample format: `12.01.13` (i.e. YY.MM.DD), which is supposed to represent the 13th of January 2012. So I tried the following query in Access:

```
SELECT * FROM [Contacts 2012]
  order by Surname, CDate(Format(Date, "0000-00-00"));
```

However, I receive this error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

So I figure I am getting close. I tried a few different formats, plus maybe DateValue, but to be honest I can't remember. I have looked at other posts both in and outside of stackoverflow, but to no avail.

Comment: Hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query

Answer (score 2):

You said your dates are strings in *YY.MM.DD* format. If that is correct for all the stored `[Date]` values ... which means `Len([Date]) = 8` for all rows ... those values will sort in the same order whether you sort them as text or transform them to Date/Time values.

So I'll suggest this query ...

```
SELECT *
FROM [Contacts 2012]
ORDER BY Surname, [Date];
```

If that returns what you want, you can avoid the data type error you're getting when attempting to transform the strings to actual dates.  Also, with an index on the `[Date]` column, the query will execute significantly faster.

Note this approach is not suitable if some of your `[Date]` values are *not* in *YY.MM.DD* format, eg *"12.1.13"*.

Comment: This nearly works. The only issue i have is when the Surname is blank. Then it lists march to december first followed by january to march i.e 12.03.## to 12.12.##; then 12.01.## to 12.03.##.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Please edit your question to include a representative sample of rows and then show us how that sample should look when sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Regex.Replace` for date format and `Regex.Split` to add 2 digits to year.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure how i actually finally resolved this but if memory serves i actually sorted the database manually by opening the database in access naturally and sorted by the surname column alphabetically and then sorted by the date column either manually or through a select statement.