# Undefined function 'STR_TO_DATE' in expression mysql msacess

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I get the following error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E14): Undefined function 'STR_TO_DATE' in expression.

when I run this query

```
SELECT 
    ProductCode, 
    Description, 
    SUM(Quantity) as Quantity, 
    STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(DateIn, '-', '/'), '%m/%d/%Y') as DateIn 
FROM 
    Product as P, 
    StockIn as S 
WHERE 
    S.ProductNo = P.ProductNo 
    AND 
    STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(DateIn, '-', '/'), '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '" + StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' AND '" + EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' GROUP BY P.ProductNo, DateIN ORDER BY DateIn, Description";
```

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` exists in MySQL; you seem to be talking to access - does access have a `STR_TO_DATE` function?

Comment: You'll have more luck if you use 'access' and 'sql' tags. This has nothing to do with c# or winforms.

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? `str_to_date` is vendor specific. If I remember correctly, it should by MySql. It will not work with SQL Server, for instance.

Comment: possibly a dupe of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Date in MS Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query)

Answer (score 0):

Try with Access SQL:

```
"SELECT
    ProductCode, 
    Description, 
    SUM(Quantity) as Quantity, 
    DateValue(DateIn) as DateIn 
FROM 
    Product as P, 
    StockIn as S 
WHERE 
    S.ProductNo = P.ProductNo 
    AND 
    DateValue(DateIn) BETWEEN #" + StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "# AND #" + EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "# GROUP BY P.ProductNo, DateValue(DateIn) ORDER BY DateValue(DateIn), Description";
```