# Access - string to date - date + time

Tags: ms-access

I have a table `t_am_chat` and from this table I use column Date_creat --> Format String in this format 2020-01-01T02:39:45

Goal is transfer to date type DateTime, ideal in format yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm:ss
Any tips please? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert String to Date in MS Access Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vasku, try this:

```
CDate(Replace(Date_creat,"T"," "))
```

To test it put copy this to Immediate window of VBE:

```
?CDate(Replace("2020-01-01T02:39:45","T"," " ))
```

After hitting Enter you should get this result:

1/1/2020 2:39:45 AM