# How to put date type into an access column using any text format with SQL function conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ms-access

I am trying to do something that seems to me very elementary. But I still don't find the solution.

I have an application tailored to work with several DBMS, Oracle, SQL Server and Access.

The matter is to insert a column data; I built translation function (to convert with SQL function) to convert text string containing the data in format "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS" and they work for Oracle and SQL Server.
I just want to put the data from text in my format into date datatype and reversely get the text in my format from date datatype.
I found how to get text formatted from date, that is "". But I can't find the reverse, put MY text format into a date.

In Oracle:

date to char

```
return(std::string("TO_CHAR(") + op + ", " + "'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'" + ")");
```

char to date

```
return(std::string("TO_DATE('") + op + "', " + "'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'" + ")");
```

In SQL Server:

date to char

```
return(std::string() + "Convert(nvarchar(30), " + op + ", 20)");
```

char to date

```
return(std::string("Convert(datetime, \'") + op + "\', 20)");
```

In Access:

date to char

```
return(std::string("FORMAT(") + op + ", " + "'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS'" + ")");
```

char to date

```
???
```

bye

Comment: Hello, I think you want to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query#:~:text=5%20Answers&text=Use%20the%20DateValue()%20function,easiest%20way%20of%20doing%20this.&text=Hit%20Ctrl%20%2B%20S%20and%20save%20the%20module%20as%20modDateConversion%20.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return(std::string("CDate(" + op + ")");
```

Comment: Thank you.
To say the true this is the way I fixed it, to make the application work.
But this solution is related to the Windows regional settings. That is, it works with the current regional settings, but if they would change ?
To definitively close the matter I think I need a trasformation from text to date where I can detail the format in which the text is, like the opposite way from Date to text. This is the way Oracle and SQL Server do.
bye

Comment: _ if they would change?_ ... then it will still work as you are using the universal ISO sequence.

Comment: I red the MS documentation and found:

"CDate recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system. The correct order of day, month, and year may not be determined if it is provided in a format other than one of the recognized date settings".

But I put United States regional setting and date format MM/DD/YYYY and the CDate still accept "2021/03/04 00:00:00" as 4 of march 2021. Only the default output of the Date without formatting is "04/03/2021".
So it seems that this is a fixed format. I am ok with this, by now. But I am not satisfied of this simplified behaviour
bye

Comment: _the default output of the Date without formatting is "04/03/2021"_ ... Not sure what you mean. The output of `Date` is a DateTime value (numeric, having no format), not a string. For display, a default format according to the system settings of Windows is used, if not a specific format is applied.

Comment: Executing a select in a query inside Access a text will be displayed:

SELECT m.data_misura FROM Misure AS m where m.codice = 1;
29/03/2021 14:15:16
This is regional setting with short date "DD/MM/YYYY".  bye

Comment: Yes. And if that format doesn't fit your purpose, specify another in the property sheet. It has no influence on the values returned.