# Fetch data from MSSQL which compares dates from DatePicker but the data fetched is always wrong

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently doing a PHP chart system which get a From and To date from user and search data in MSSQL by comparing the two dates with dates in MSSQL.

However , my datepicker is giving correct date to be search in MSSQL , for example I selected a From date : 6/12/2021 and a To date : 6/15/2021 (dateformat : m/dd/yy) but when I submit the dates to fetch data, if there is no data in between these dates, it will give me data from 6/12/2020 - 6/15/2021 which is what I dont want. Is there something wrong with my chart or my query ?

I am using AnyChart as my php chart system.

Below is what I echo out from my From and To variable together with the data that i fetched from sql based on the dates

[image]

As you can see the date fetched is in 2020 not 2021.

**Here is my code for comparing dates and fetch data**

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_POST['Search'])){
            $From=$_POST['From'];
            $To=$_POST['to'];
            $conn = odbc_connect("Ingot_Daily_Report", "", "");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM Output_Data WHERE data_Day BETWEEN '$From' AND '$To'";
            $sql = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
            while($row=odbc_fetch_array($sql)){
            ?>  
            ['<?php echo $row['data_Day']; ?>', <?php echo $row['Crystal_Out']; ?>, <?php echo $row['Aggressive_Daily_Target']; ?>, <?php echo $row['KPI_Target']; ?>, <?php echo $row['AverageToDate']; ?>],
            <?php   
            }
            }
?>
```

**My JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'm/dd/yy'
    });
    $(function(){
        $("#From").datepicker({
             
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
             $("#To").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);

        }

        });
        $("#To").datepicker({
            
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#From").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);

                }
        });
    });
              
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please check the date format in your database and change your date format accordingly. Also, check if the date column is of type datetime.

Comment: What if it is in longtext format ? @AmitVerma

Comment: in case of long text format the comparison may be wrong.

Comment: Alright ill try it out @AmitVerma

Comment: Is my usage of BETWEEN correct ? @AmitVerma

Comment: What is the actual data type of the `data_Day` column and what does `var_dump($From);` output? Thanks.

Comment: @SteveKush yes, between is correct.

Comment: @Zhorov The datatype at first is ShortText , however after i changed it to Date/Time in Access, it says datatype mismatch

Comment: @SteveKush The data type of the `data_Day` is the actual reason for this unexpected behaviour. When you sotre dates as text, the order is different (`6/17/2020` is between `6/16/2021` and `6/17/2021`). Fix your database design and always store datetime values using the appropriate data type. And, if you use MS Access, mark the question with the appropriate tag, MS Access is not MS SQL Server.

Comment: Do you guys have any idea how to not have data type mismatch after i changed my access datatype based on my  query ? @AmitVerma

Comment: I am still getting datatype mismatch after i change to date/time format in access

Comment: @Zhorov how is 6/17/2020 between 6/17/2021 ? what is the use of the year then?

Comment: @SteveKush The value `6/17/2020` is between `6/16/2021` and `6/17/2021` when these values are text and are compared as text. If you store the date using the appropriate date data type in MS Access, the result will be different. I don't have enough experience with MS Access, but this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query) may help.

Comment: @Zhorov the error tells me there is a datatype mismatch tho haizz.