# ms-access sql string with date and time

Tags: sql, ms-access, date-conversion

Here is the Baptism programmer again.

In the database there are 2 tables:

1. ImportDoopAanvragen : imported from a Google-form
2. Werktabel : the records from the first table but altered to a more workable format.

In the first table I always import all the records (of people who filled in the form).
In the second table I only want to append the new records from the first table.

I want to select them based on a datefield (date+time). In the first table the date is American, in the second table European.

I convert the date with this statement:

```
stempelstring = "#" & month(stempel) & "/" & Day(stempel) & "/" & Year(stempel) & "# " & Hour(stempel) & ":" & Minute(stempel) & ":" & Second(stempel)
```

I insert this statement in an sql string LSQL

```
 LSQL = "DELETE * FROM [ImportDoopAanvragen] WHERE Tijdstempel <= '" & stempelstring & "'"
```

When I run this code I always get error 3464 data types do not match in criteria expression.

I think because my parameter stempelstring is a string and the field Tijdstempel is a datefield.
I don't know how to convert stempelstring in a date without loosing the hours, minutes and seconds.

I tried to change de string into a date again with

```
stempel = DateValue(stempelstring)
```

I formatted stempel as a variant, but even when I format it as a date it gives an error

Comment: It will mainly depend on the format your string field contains for the date value to be correct converted. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/convert-string-to-date-in-ms-access-query

Comment: I saw the stackoverflow.com/questions/17361338/… I saw it before but I was confused about the large number at the end and I didn't understand it. Now I just used what I saw en edited my string in LSQL = "DELETE * FROM [ImportDoopAanvragen] WHERE Format(ImportDoopAanvragen.Tijdstempel,'yyyyMMddHhNnSs') <= '" & stempelstring & "'"  . I get no errors but could not test yet if the old records are deleted. Thank you very mutch Jorge

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Format` and *octothorpes* for the string expression of the date/time value:

```
stempelstring = Format(stempel, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss")
```

and:

```
LSQL = "DELETE * FROM [ImportDoopAanvragen] WHERE Tijdstempel <= #" & stempelstring & "#"
```

Comment: I Thank everyone who helped me solving my problem. Everything is working now

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a select statement first, if that works, you can convert it to a delete statement
First select just the date:
SELECT DateValue(stempelstring);
After that get the records as Gustav proposed, and if that works delete them.

Furthermore, if you say you convert the date, be specific as to what table you are working with, month day year format is American, nothing European about it. I had to read your problem twice.