# How to select all ms access table records based on date

Tags: sql, ms-access

i'm new to MS Access..

one of my Access table `CHECKOUT` having a column name `CHECK-TIME` with `Date/time` `data type`

values in that column are like `7/15/2013 10:56:22 AM`,`9/19/2013 6:54:37 PM....`

```
i want to select the data based on  date like  `7/15/2013'
```

how to write the query for this task ???

thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168529/sql-access-how-to-return-between-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the way to specify date literals is with hash (#) not any form of quote or backtick.

Secondly, you can't do LIKE comparisons with dates, not that I've ever seen anyway.

Thirdly, it's always best to specify dates in yyyy-mm-dd format because it's an unambiguous format.

This example should give you what you need:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  CHECKOUT
WHERE
  datevalue([CHECK-TIME]) = #2013-07-15#
```

The `datevalue()` function takes a parameter, usually a string but in this case a datetime, and converts it to a date, thus stripping off the time. This allows us to check for equality against a date literal.

Comment: ThankQ Benjamin Warren