# Access SQL Statement to retrieve all data between two dates

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, datetimepicker, oledbcommand

I need help with coding to get all data within two dates, with two `DateTimePickers`.

- `dtpDateFrom`
- `dtpDateTo`

So if I put `dtpDateFrom = 06/01/14` and `dtpDateTo = 06/30/14`, I'd get all data in June.

I have this code so far:

```
Public Shared Function GetNoofHoursofTImeIn(ByVal search As String, ByVal dfrom As DateTime, ByVal dto As Datetime) As DataTable

    Dim dtoffenseinfo As New DataTable

    If Not DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        DBConnection.Open()
    Else

    End If


    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT sum(No_of_Hour) as THour from EmployeeAttendance where EmployeeID='" & search & "'" & _
                                          "and Format(WorkingDate, 'Short Date')>='" & Format(dfrom, "Short Date") & _
                                  "' and Format(WorkingDate, 'Short Date')<='" & Format(dto, "Short Date") & "'", DBConnection)

    adapter.Fill(dtoffenseinfo)
    DBConnection.Close()


    Return dtoffenseinfo
End Function
```

I have data in 6/09/14 and 6/12/14 but it's not functioning properly.

So I'm looking for a perfect code for this objective.

Many thanks! A major feature I'm working on for weeks.

Comment: Your code appears to be MS Access so I added the right tag.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if the db columns are actual Date types (they should be) then you can use BETWEEN see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3168598/1070452

Comment: Why not using a query parameters. Than you no need to worry about dateformat. Just compare with `Between`

Answer (score 0):

try this in your query....
you can use between operator here for more simple.. and please check the date format also means what you are passing and what format is stored in DB.

```
"SELECT sum(No_of_Hour) as THour from EmployeeAttendance where EmployeeID='" & search & "'" & _
                                          "and Format(WorkingDate, 'Short Date') between(" & Format(dfrom, "Short Date") & _
                                  ","& Format(WorkingDate, 'Short Date')& ")"
```

Comment: Great! I'll try to fix this since I'm getting an "Expression expected" at the comma in the last "Format(WorkingDate, 'Short Date') & ")" . Thanks for the suggestion @K.K.Agarwal!

Comment: Formats do not affect how the values are stored in the table.
If you want only the date portion, use the DateValue function and for efficiency do not operate on the field value.
WorkingDate Between '" & DateValue(dFrom) & "' AND '" & DateValue(dTo) + 1 & "'"
note the +1 with dTo. This allows you to include values containing a time component without converting them all to date only values - much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You are converting your dates to strings for comparison.  So, you end up with a strings like '6/09/14' and '6/12/14'.  Well, guess what, '6/10/13' is between these values.  So is '6/10/22'.   For string comparisons to work, you need to format your dates as YYYY-MM-DD (or YYYYMMDD).

Remove the `format()` function and do the comparisons as dates.

Comment: Hmm. I used Format('Short Date') to remove the TIME values I'm getting from the DateTimePickers. Yes, I could be missing something there perhaps.

Comment: @user3522506 . . . I don't actually know how to insert a date constant from VBA to Access.  That is all that you need, though.

Comment: alright I've bad experience reading correct date formats before but I'll fiddle with them again until I get it right and finally come up with a constant kind of solution. Many thanks! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the comments to the question, you really should be using a parameterized query. In your particular case the code would look something like this:

```vb
Public Shared Function GetNoofHoursofTImeIn(ByVal search As String, ByVal dfrom As DateTime, ByVal dto As DateTime) As DataTable
    Dim dtoffenseinfo As New DataTable

    If Not DBConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        DBConnection.Open()
    End If

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = DBConnection
        cmd.CommandText = _
                "SELECT SUM(No_of_Hour) AS THour FROM EmployeeAttendance " & _
                "WHERE EmployeeID = ? " & _
                    "AND WorkingDate BETWEEN ? AND ?"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", search)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dfrom.Date)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dto.Date)
        Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            adapter.Fill(dtoffenseinfo)
        End Using
    End Using

    DBConnection.Close()
    Return dtoffenseinfo
End Function
```

Comment: Aww. I'm getting a "Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid." Could I be having data type conflicts in MS Access? Thanks for the knowledge! I'll try to Google this error in this case though.